# I use a MAC and I was told to backup my code and track my work

Tags: git, macos, github

Task:

Pushing code up to the repository.

In order to backup your code and track your work, you'll want to commit the changes you've made to the project's repository. You'll have to open up the terminal and cd into the correct folder that holds the cloned repository for this assignment. Once there, you'll have to complete these three steps:

1) Stage your code

> git add -a

2) Create a version of your staged code

> git commit -m 'created game logic'

3) Push your code to the GitHub repository

> git push origin master

My end result:

```
Roberts-MacBook-Air:wdi-fundamentals-memorygame robert$ git add -a
error: unknown switch `a'
usage: git add [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -v, --verbose         be verbose

    -i, --interactive     interactive picking
    -p, --patch           select hunks interactively
    -e, --edit            edit current diff and apply
    -f, --force           allow adding otherwise ignored files
    -u, --update          update tracked files
    -N, --intent-to-add   record only the fact that the path will be added later
    -A, --all             add changes from all tracked and untracked files
    --ignore-removal      ignore paths removed in the working tree (same as --no-all)
    --refresh             don't add, only refresh the index
    --ignore-errors       just skip files which cannot be added because of errors
    --ignore-missing      check if - even missing - files are ignored in dry run
    --chmod <(+/-)x>      override the executable bit of the listed files

Roberts-MacBook-Air:wdi-fundamentals-memorygame robert$ git commit -m 'created game logic'
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Roberts-MacBook-Air:wdi-fundamentals-memorygame robert$ git push origin master
Username for 'https: //github.com ': myusername
Password for 'https: //myusername@github.com': 
remote: Permission to ga-students/wdi-fundamentals-memorygame.git  denied to myusername.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github /ga-students/wdi-fundamentals-memorygame.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I can't even enter my password, well I type it out nothing prints out and when I hit enter I get the above error message. I've read the answers to this question and I'm not able to resolve it. Please help, thank you.

Comment: maybe what you want is ```git add -A```, at the first step. And since you didn't commit anything, you got ```nothing to commit``` at the second step; but the error you encountered at the third step maybe caused by your wrong password.

Comment: Did you read what git tried to tell you? Do you understand what `git commit - m` is supposed to do? Have you read any material about git so far?

Comment: "Unknown switch \`a´" looks like you have a really frightfully old or just otherwise incompatible Git version (perhaps aliased to a different comrmand?) - try installing a fresher one e.g. with Homebrew, or do the first exercises on a different computer until you get a hang of the basics.

Comment: Did you get git through XCode or another way?  If XCode, how old is your mac and what version of OS X are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to solution left by *@RohitShedage*, you can run `git add --all` or `git add -A`.

Bare in mind, `git add .` will only work with files the `git` is already tracking.

Answer (score 0):

please try `git add .` instead of `git add -a`

Answer (score 0):

Try `git add -A`, not `git add -a`

Comment: Add more explanation to your answer